# Chinese Idiom puzzle 5

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. You are not a gentleman if you don't take revenge for a wrong against you - 見:《施公案》六四回
2. People in the world are all brothers - 出自:先秦·孔子《論語·顏淵》
3. Give no quarters
4. Reply other's hatred with kindness - 出自:《論語·憲問》
5. The opposite bank of the river - 出自:《詩經·國風·秦風》的《蒹葭》
6. Perfect - 出自:《雪月梅傳》《周禮·天官冢宰下·醫師》
7. One call and hundreds respond - 出自: 明·天然癡叟《石魚頭》
8. Contribution cannot be uncredited - 見:《清史稿．卷三八七．列傳．陳孚恩》
9. Stick to the old, refuse to make any change 語本:《禮記．王制》
10. Eliminate the rebellious ministers around the monarch
11. Chivalrous bone,  red heart
12. humane
13. Chinese emperor's self-address
14. When faced with a crisis, can deal with it calmly without panic
15. Drink poison to quench thirst (A metaphor for only solves the immediate difficulties and ignores future disasters.)
16. Make an unrealistic request (usu with an evil person); make deal with dangerous people; courting disaster [literal] ask a tiger for its skin - 語本《太平御覽》
17. Dangers are hidden everywhere
18. The imperial edict. It is a kind of self-criticism issued by ancient Chinese monarchs.
19. A forced peace treaty, (signed when the enemy’s army is threatening the capital)
20. After leaving Yangguan West Road, there are no more old friends. 出自:王維 《陽關三疊》

A. It is used to describe the life of primitive people who can't use fire and eat meat raw and bloody. 出自:《礼记·礼运》

B. Generally, it means that the male and female both love each other or one loves the other, but cannot be together for various reasons.

C. Unity; of one mind

D. Dig a well to get water when you are thirsty (meaning it is too late to find a solution when the matter is already urgent.)

E. Stay firm and unwavering, not subject to changes due to the complexity of the external environment

F. A gentleman doesn't stand on the side of a dangerous wall (meaning a gentleman must stay away from dangerous places) - 出處:《孟子·盡心》

G. Wait ten years to take revenge is not too late for a gentleman (Means that people need not be impatient to avenge, wait for the opportunity to do it) - 見:《兒女風塵記》

H. No one noticed you spent ten years studying (下一句是: 一舉成名天下知) - 出自: 元·劉祁《歸潛志》第七卷

I. Inner beauty

J. A tiger left the mountain and fell into the flat ground to be trapped - 出自:清·錢彩《說岳全傳》

K. A general's victory comes with the price of having thousands of soldiers die 出自:《己亥歲感事》唐·曹松

L. Round inside, square outside (refers to a person whose appearance is upright, but his heart is smooth.

M. One's mind is clear and tranquil, have very few desire

N. The ideal relationship between brothers 見:《史記．卷一．五帝本紀》

O. Means to put yourself in consideration for others -《論語·衛靈公》：“己所不欲，勿施於人”朱熹集注

More hints below

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm back!

"君子不立危墙下" and "与虎谋皮" is a little difficult for me, and "有仇不报非君子".

> [image: My Answer]

Comment: My answer for (C) is 一心一德,  but 一心一意 seems correct too. (G) 君子報仇十年不晚 is correct, I would accept 未 instead of 不 too. Great job! (Wait, 德 is in the word hint)

Comment: Thanks @TangHo . By the way, would you like to add some new rules, such as searching on the Internet or books?

Comment: No such rule, searching the internet or book is what I want people to do